# java strings concept for palindrome

Tags: java, string

I am attempting to find out if a given `String` is a palindrome, However, it never get's into the `if` block that prints *"given string is a palindrome"* even when *it is* a palindrome.

```
String s;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter any string");
s = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("contents of string s " + s);
scan.close();

StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer(s);
System.out.println("contents of stringbuffer " + stringbuffer);
stringbuffer = stringbuffer.reverse();

System.out.println("contents of reversed stringbuffer " + stringbuffer);
if(s.equals(stringbuffer))
{
    System.out.println(" given string is a palindrome");
}
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: From first sight it looks okay. put a break point on the IF statement and see what makes the difference. could be encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if(s.equals(stringbuffer))` Here you are trying to compare `String` with `StringBuffer` which will always return `false`.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is how internally **[.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))** method works. So first it will check that other object is `instanceOf String` or not. So here it will return `false` so `.equals()` method will end up in giving `false` as output in every case.

You can use there **[s.contentEquals(stringbuffer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer))** to compare both or convert `StringBuffer` to `String` and call `String.equals()` Method.

```
if(s.contentEquals(stringbuffer))
{
    System.out.println(" given string is a palindrome");
}
```

or convert `StringBuffer` to `String` and then call `.equals()` method,

```
if(s.equals(stringbuffer.toString()))
{
    System.out.println(" given string is a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it's internal implementation.

Comment: @PrasadS If you found any of the answers useful, Accept it!

Comment: I am unable to do that as I am having only 13 reputation points. Else I would have done that. Thank you once again

Comment: I don't think we require that much reputation to accept an answer.

Comment: @PrasadS no it doesn't. Are you sure you're trying it correctly ? Its the check button(gray) on the left.

Answer (score 3):

In your `if` condition, you are comparing 2 different type of objects. Remember `String` & `StringBuffer` are 2 different classes, hence their object won't be equal. 
In order to get the proper result, you need to get the `String` object out of StringBuffer....

So `if(s.equals(stringbuffer.toString()))` would work for you.

Answer (score 2):

you're comparing a type `String` and a type `StringBuffer` with [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) hence it will *never* get into the `if` block.

The [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) not only compares the `String` contents but also checks if the other object is an instance of a `String`

you're looking for [`String#contentEquals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals-java.lang.CharSequence-) which doesnt do type checking.

```
if(s.contentEquals(stringbuffer))
{
     System.out.println(" given string is a palindrome");
}
```

or convert the `StringBuffer` variable to a type `String` prior to comparison.

```
if(s.equals(stringbuffer.toString()))
{
     System.out.println(" given string is a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the second method which you have suggested earlier. It's working fine. Thank you